# Como transformar um hash em uma cor

Tags: php, cores

Como transformar um hash em uma cor aleatória.. Vejam que usei a expressão “hash” apenas para falar que um aglomerado de letras/numeros podem ser transformados em cores, como este:

```
d0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940
```

é sem nexo, sem sentido mas sempre que for usado esse hash ele vai dar uma cor em especifico e caso seja trocado o final `0` por `1` vai mostrar outra cor.. ou mesmo se for trocado qualquer parte do hash ele vai mostrar cores diferentes.

Obs: creio eu que existem infinitas formas de montar um hash mas não tenho certeza se existem infinitas cores então  não tem problema se hashs diferentes derem uma cor igual ***(mesmo nao sendo o ideal)***

Conseguem entender?, o formato da cor eu gostaria que fosse RGB porém pode ser no estilo `#FFFFFF` não faço distinção, eu pensei em algo assim: Pegar três partes do hash uma no inicio outra no meio outra no fim e partir dela trabalhar pra pegar cores, mas como não sei como gerar essas cores depois de pegar essas partes eu venho recorrer ajuda..

Comment: Você pode fazer em array e montar uma função de leitura conforme a hash passada... Se for hash x retorna cor x senão retorna cor y

Comment: Você vai armazenar esses hashs e cores em algum lugar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondendo diretamente à pergunta a forma de transformar uma hash numa cor será:

```
function hashToColor($hash) {
  $code = dechex(crc32($hash));
  $code = substr($code, 0, 6);
  return $code;
}
```

Obviamente o exemplo pode ser otimizado mas esta é a solução que lhe entrego. Simples e direta para fácil entendimento.

No entanto deve de ponderar a utilização do `CRC32` logo de origem tendo obviamente em atenção a possibilidade de colisões etc.

Answer (score 0):

Já que não existe relação alguma entre o seu `hash` e a cor que ele vai representar, esse processo é totalmente randômico.

Você não especificou como esse `hash` esta sendo gerado então vou mostrar apenas como você pode gerar o valor para cores no formato **hexadecimal**

```
echo sprintf("#%06x",rand(0,16777215));
```

Este código irá gerar valores como: `#7bdc39`.

Agora você pode associar cada novo `hash` com este comando.